# expr, eval or test to check for returned value

Tags: bash

I have a simple database query I wrapped in my bash script.

In case my query retrieves one row, I want to do several things. If my query retrieves zero rows, I want to terminate my script gracefully.

What is the best way to check if my script retrieves zero rows?  Can you please provide some pointers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working bash script to get number of rows from the DB. Just pass the variables and replace FROM part of the sql with yours.

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMROWS=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORDd@//$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$ORACLE_SID   << EOF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGES 0
select count(*) from dual;
exit success
EOF`
echo $NUMROWS
```

HINT:
Replace the last line echo $NUMROWS with exit $NUMROWS and your script will exit gracefully if there are no records. Wrap it in a bash if statement if you want to do other things, as below.

```
if [ $NUMROWS -lt 1 ]; then
  #exit gracefully
  exit 0; 
fi

# do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the command `do_it`.  Then, the simplest thing that comes to mind is:

```
do_it | while read x; do 
    # do whatever you want ...
done
```

In this case, that block won't be run if there are no results

Comment: However, with this pipeline, you will not be able to set a variable to denote "success" and check the variable after the while loop: due to the pipe, bash will run the while loop in a sub-shell, and any variables you set in the while loop body will disappear when the sub-shell exits.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: the trick is to use /dev/null.

```
#!/bin/bash
DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
BIN="/users/db2inst1/sqllib/bin"
OUT=`${BIN}/db2 connect to myschema > /dev/null 
${BIN}/db2 -x "SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WITH UR"
${BIN}/db2 quit > /dev/null
`
echo $OUT
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Answering your own question Chris? You could have just updated the question itself with a modified version of the Oracle solution.